# Does [Authorize(Users="name1,name2")] exist in AspNetCore?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to use the [Authorize] attribute in a Asp.net core2 webapi. It seems that the AuthorizeAttribute does not have a Users property (but does have Roles). What happened to this functionality? Is there a different way now? (I am using AD authentication so my question may be moot if that is how I'm supposed to do it.

Comment: It's not added but you can create a custom authorize attribute which implements your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't exist but you can achieve the same thing by:

a) Creating your custom authorize attribute. Read more about it on [How do you create a custom AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core)

b) Creating a policy for those users. If you are going to have multiple actions assigned to the same users and they don't share the same role, you can create a policy. Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: OK. It also seems that creating custom roles requires a lot as well. Is it advisable to create a table in my database, access it from the controller, search for a user's permissions and use this information before proceeding with additional data CRUD?

Comment: Normally you set a list of roles as a string with the identity of the user. That way, you don't need to do a round trip to the database in order to authorize a user.

Comment: I see that. But, unless I create custom roles that have meaning in my programming context, I have to use the Roles available to me in the AAD. Creating roles requires command lines and a fair amount of work. Theres no Portal UI that lets you create a Role like "Librarian" or "LibraryUser"

Comment: I always create roles in my applications to have more control.

Comment: OK. Which technique do you use? There seem to be a few command line opportunities

Comment: I just create User, UserRole, UserUserRole tables, cache them and use them to enable/disable features inside each page.